# How to see if form has any data in it Django

Tags: django, django-forms

If i have a form say `recipe` and in it a charfield that can be left blank say `serves` how do i check to see in my view if the user has left the field blank or not?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
form = MyForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    if form.cleaned_data['serves'] == "":
        ...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data

Comment: could i do something like?
`if form.serves:`